# How to encode a string for displaying in HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs

I have created a webpage to create a post. For taking description, I have used CKEDITOR. When I save data in mongo database it is saved as:

```
'<p>How are you?</p>\r\n'
```

But when I fetch this and display it in my ejs file, then I got an error that is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

After fetching the content looks like this:

```
"&lt;p&gt;How are you?&lt;/p&gt;"
```

Can you help me out in this? Thanks in advance.
And also ask me if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode HTML content by using decodeURIComponent. for more details (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
  const uri = "&lt;p&gt;How are you?&lt;/p&gt";
  const decodeUri = decodeURIComponent(uri);
  console.log(decodeUri)
```